# Can't run application built using libboost 1.49 in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, dpkg, 22.04, libraries, boost

I am trying to install an application that was developed in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. This application (I have not access to the source code) requires to have installed 'libboost_system.1.49'.

Now I have to install this application in an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and as I could imagine, there are some compatibility issues.

First, I tried to install and run the last version of the Boost library, the 1.74, but the application is not running with it and is still requesting the version 1.49.

I've seen some related links talking about how to uninstall version X of this package to install a newer or an older version, but after following the procedures explained in those threads, I still couldn't make it run.

I tried this: [Uninstall boost and install another version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430332/uninstall-boost-and-install-another-version) with no success.
Also this: [Installation instructions from the official website](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html)
I downloaded the Boost version from here: [Download link from official website](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_49_0.html)

I tried to check the version of the library installed by running: `dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'` and the response is that "the package is not installed and no information is available"

The exception that the Terminal is showing says: `AppName: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.49.0: cannot openshared object file: No such file or directory`

As with the JAVA_HOME path, there is a way to specify in Ubuntu the path to which the app needs to go to retrieve the Boost libraries with the version installed?

Also I tried is to execute the following commands:

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

and

```
sudo ./b2 --with=all -j $cpuCores install
```

, from inside the downloaded folder of the Boost version, but it installed the boost libraries under /usr/local/include instead of in /usr/include.

To conclude, the last thing I tried is to run the last command adding the --prefix instruction:

```
sudo ./b2 --with=all -j $cpuCores install --prefix=/usr/include
```

But then I check the version again and is still saying that libboost-dev is not installed.

Always when I try to install the libboost-dev package, it installs the last version of Boost, instead the 1.49, and I tried to install the libboost-all-dev_1.49.0.1_i386.deb package, which is the only one I could find in the launchpad.net repository, but when running the command `sudo dpkg -i libboost-all-dev_1.49.0.1_i386.deb`, the Terminal brings a dpkg error saying that "dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-all-dev:i386", and says that it depends on "libboost-dev"... which is the one that, If I install it, I will get the latest version of the Boost package, which is not compatible...

Can I install and link, in some manner, the version 1.49 of the Boost library in an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS? I don't care about not to have the last version of this library, as the PC where it will be installed will not have any applications installed. Only the one that depends on this 1.49 version.

Any help you could give me would be much appreciated

Comment: If the question is not clear or I need to add some more information please let me know! I am going crazy wih this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a symbolic link of the current 1.7.4 library to the 1.4.9?

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.49.0
```